# Wait for husky commit-msg hook to finish completely and run Enquirer

Tags: npm, npm-scripts, enquire.js, husky, git-husky

I have a script that I runs during a Git commit to get the current commit message using Husky's `commit-msg` hook, with that script I make HTTP requests.
My challenge is to run another script after the Husky hook script is done.
The script I want to run uses the [Enquirer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enquirer) NPM package.
I tried running the script that contain the code for Enquirer within a `post-commit` hook from Husky but what happens is that both scripts are ran at the same time and the second script exits with the `commit-msg`,
So I want a way to wait for `commit-msg` to completely finish and then I run the one with Enquirer.
I tried resolving the issue by following this [thread](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/issues/753) but the child process also exits with the `commit-msg`.
The output looks something like 
[image]

Any ideas on how to circumvent this? thanks.

Below is the husky config
[image]

Comment: Have you tried utilizing the [wait-on](https://github.com/jeffbski/wait-on) package?

Comment: @RobC, no how do you mean? Can I wait for a Node process to finish, I cannot see that in the docs

Comment: Share configuration for your hook, what version of husky you're running?

Comment: Hey @OluwafemiSule, it is version 4.2.1.
Check updated question for hook config.